# get a lowercase column from ResultSet using column name

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using Oracle 12cr1 database. Looks like I can not get a value from `ResultSet` using the column name if the column name is lowercase.

Create table `create table "Tab" (col number, "col" varchar2(10))`, so the second column is lowercase. If I call `getString("col")` I will get the value of the first column. If I call `getString("\"col\"")` I will get *Invalid column name* error.

However, it works fine if I use column index.

Comment: So, you have two columns with the same name?

Comment: Apparently this is very bad practice. Just testing another implementation of JDBC and comparing it with Oracle JDBC implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the JDBC API documentation of [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) (emphasis mine):

> **Column names used as input to getter methods are case insensitive**. When a getter method is called with a column name and several columns have the same name, the value of the first matching column will be returned. The column name option is designed to be used when column names are used in the SQL query that generated the result set. For columns that are NOT explicitly named in the query, it is best to use column numbers. If column names are used, **the programmer should take care to guarantee that they uniquely refer to the intended columns, which can be assured with the SQL AS clause**.

In other words, for the API column names (or, more correctly, column labels) are case insensitive, so what you want is not possible. You will need to make your column labels unique by providing an `AS` column label, or you should get the column by index instead.

Comment: I'm assuming the same is true for the `update` methods, although it is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @Roland Yes, the column names for the `updateXXX` methods follow the same rules as for the `getXXX` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Since one shouldn't be using `SELECT *` in production anyway, renaming the column in the `SELECT` will fix the problem:

```
SELECT
    col AS col1
,   "col" AS col2
FROM "Tab"
```

Now your two columns have different aliases, avoiding the ambiguity.

Comment: Yeah, I know this way I can get the result. I am checking some edge cases and found I just can not get the value using the column name if I don't specify an column alias without double quoting it.