# jdbc left join 3 tables

Tags: java, jdbc

There are three tables `<Table 1>, <Table 2> and <Table 3>`

My SQL is something like this:

```
"Select table1.col1, table1.col2, table1.col3, table2.col4, table2.col5, table2.col6, 
table3.col7, table3.col8 from Table 1 as table1 
LEFT JOIN Table 2 as table2 on (table1.col1 = table2.col4) 
LEFT JOIN Table 3 as table3 on (table1.col1 = table3.col8)"
```

The normal way to get the resultset is:

```
public List getExportDataList() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
Connection connect = null;
String url = "jdbc:.....";

String username = "username ";
String password = "password ";

try {
   connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
   System.out.println("in exec");
   System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}

List dataList = new ArrayList<>();
PreparedStatement pstmt = connect.prepareStatement(
  THE SQL CODE SHOWN ABOVE
}

ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){
Table1 table1 = new Table1();

table1.setCOL1(rs.getString("col1"));
table1.setCOL2(rs.getString("col2"));

dataList.add(table1);
}
rs.close();
pstmt.close();
connect.close();
return dataList;
}
```

so that the "dataList" can be used to display the data in Primefaces dataTable.

However, this way only can save the columns in Table1 to the "dataList". I tried to `dataList.add(table2)` as well as `dataList.add(table3)` at the same time, but there is an error : "/reportGenerate.xhtml @50,75 value="#{reportData.dateCreated}": The class 'net.picary.model.Liaison' does not have the property 'dateCreated'."

Can someone tell me how to save all the selected columns from the three tables into "dataList"? Or any alternative way to achieve it?

Comment: Please show the exact code you use and the error(s) you get. Also be aware that when you retrieve values by column name, you need to make sure those names are unique. Right now you have multiple columns `col1` in your result set, but you'll only be able to retrieve the first one with that name, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42410902/466862).

Comment: As @Mark suggests, you may need to use column aliases to ensure that the column names in your ResultSet are unique: `SELECT table1.col1 AS t1_col1, table2.col1 AS t2_col1, ...`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Here is the error: 

"/reportGenerate.xhtml @50,75 value="#{reportData.dateCreated}": The class 'net.picary.model.Liaison' does not have the property 'dateCreated'."

Comment: I'm beginning to think that your problem has nothing to do with JDBC, but you are trying to shoehorn different objects with different properties in the same view. You might want to include the actual(!) code of those objects and your JSF code instead of your JDBC code.

Answer (score 1):

> error: "/reportGenerate.xhtml @50,75
>   value="#{reportData.dateCreated}": The class
>   'net.picary.model.Liaison' does not have the property 'dateCreated'."

Your problem is not with Query or JDBC, you should to make sure that attribute `dateCreated` exist in your `net.picary.model.Liaison` class with getter and setter like this :

```
private Date dateCreated;
public String name;
public String experience;

public Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}

public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}
```

So when your page `reportGenerate.xhtml` try to load this attribute it not find it, because :

1. Not exist in your class
2. It exist but it is private and without getter and setter.

So make sure that your attribute exist and have gtter and setter, this can solve your error.

**EDIT**

You have two choices :

1. When you get your result you should to use 3 List of type table1, table2, table3 and fill them in the same loop like this :

```
    List dataList1 = ...;
    List dataList2 = ...;
    List dataList3 = ...;

    while(rs.next()){
       table1 = new Table1();
       table1.setCOL1(rs.getString("col1"));
       ...
       dataList1.add(table1);

       table2 = new Table2();
       table2.setCOL1(rs.getString("col1"));
       ...
       dataList2.add(table2);

       table3 = new Table3();
       table3.setCOL1(rs.getString("col1"));
       ...
       dataList3.add(table3);
    }
```

and in your xhtml page you had to use this three List instead to one

2. Create a new Object which combine this three Table like this :

```
    class MyObject {
        private Table1 table1;
        private Table2 table2;
        //constructor
        //getters and setters
    }
```

Then create a `List<MyObject> list = ....;` and set information in each table.

Hope you get my point, good luck

Comment: The problem is, dataCreated is a column in another class. For example, Liaison is the Table 2 I mentioned above, but dataCreated belongs to Table 1. So obviously there would not have dataCreated in Liaison. Thats why I'm confused.

Comment: can you edit and provide the desin of your classes so we can understand more @vennis

Comment: I just wondering is it possible to save the data from 3 different classes into one list? I tried to "dataList.add(table1);" only, which means that I never dataList.add the other two tables. Its able to display the correct data (columns from table 1 after left join table) in the xhtml file (I comment out the columns from table 2 and table 3). But I need to display all the selected columns from the three tables, not only table 1. So I wondering is it because cannot save the data from different classes in one list?

Comment: I meant I comment out the columns from table 2 and table 3 in my p:dataTable. so only the columns from table 1 are displayed and this is working fine. it able to show me the correct columns that I want from table 1 with the correct data after left join table.

Answer (score 0):

First, Check whether column names (col1,col2,col3,..) are with same name in your code in java with all the three db tables (table1,table2,table3).

(ie)

```
...
Table1 table1 = new Table1();

table1.setCOL1(rs.getString("col1"));
table1.setCOL2(rs.getString("col2"));

dataList.add(table1);
....
```

In the above code check you have "col1" is in same name with db column in Table1,Table2,Table3.If the column name(s) is different in database and in your code ,add aliases to your MySQL query and match it with same name in your java code.

If the column name matches, then set the column value for your table 2 and 3.

Then, add it to your Datalist.

```
 ....
 ....
 table2.setCOL1(rs.getString("col1"));
 dataList.add(table2);
 ....
```

and so on. Also, check you have added try/catch for your code to avoid exceptions like Nullpointer,SQLException etc.. which may arise during SQL transactions.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. The columns names in each tables are unique.