# Leveraging spring to reduce DB calls

Tags: spring, optimization, jdbc

I have a data piece that is:

```
foo{
    string: one
    string: two
    list<string>: listOne
    list<string>: listTwo
}
```

such that in the DB one is associated with multiple entries of listOne.

not much background, I'm at a loss as to where to even look for answers. I received feed back to try to eliminate a jdbctemplate.query during a code review with a "there may be a way to reduce this using @autowire".

no code to share, I just need a place to start looking for answers. I've been on the spring website and I don't see anything that looks like I can use it. and I didn't see any google results that resemble what I'm looking for.

I should probably preface this with the fact that I'm a new dev so even a simple answer is likely not something I've tried. so this came about because my query for listOne and listTwo are returning columns. so I first tried using a mapper with the jdbcTemplate.query() that returned a string. but jdbc didn't like that. so I ended up returning a list from the mapper. then jdbc turns those answers into a list>, I then afterwards loop through those list> to convert them to a list and store them in foo. in my mind an ideal solution allows me to combine the two queries and the mapper looks like (pseudo code):

```
public foo fooMapper implements<RowMapper>(){
    foo.one = resultSet.get("thingOne")
    foo.two = resultSet.get("thingTwo")
    foo.listOne = resultSet.get("[a portion of the column]listThingOne")
    foo.listTwo = resultSet.get("[a portion of the column]listThingTwo")

    return foo;
}
```

it should be noted that the the result set is mono-directional, I found out when I tried using a string[] instead of a list.

Comment: I think you should use `SQL JOIN` to fetch all required data by a single sql query, and then map the result to corresponding fields and collections. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440741/jdbc-left-join-3-tables) answer (and the question itself) will help you to start

Comment: well, I know how to build the query, my trouble lies between the mapper and the template return type. that said, this link did give me an idea, and I appreciate it. i'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: yes, I think the new solution i have will work. I've got a bug or two to work out. I'll likely get asked if there was a spring solution. but i didn't see one, nor do i see any examples there of in the code.